# rails nested devise redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise, nested

i have an app with nested resources. my routes are:

```
resources :teams do 
  resources :blogs
end
```

in my blogs controller, im using a different layout, by adding

```
layout "teamlayout"
```

to the controller.
Both layouts, the application.html.erb and the teamlayout.html.erb have included a login form itself. which i made working by this: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app

now my question. when a user logs in, i want him redirected to the page from where he logs in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple options:

Include a hidden field value in the login form that describes the source of the login (e.g. `hidden_field_tag(:login_source, "team")`) and define your own logic for SessionsController#create that uses the hidden field value to determine the location for response_with.

Or, you could keep track of the user's location by using a before_filter in the controllers with login forms by doing something like

```
def store_location
  session['saved_location'] = request.request_uri
end
```

Then, you can override the after_sign_in_path_for(resource) method in your application controller to use the session saved_location value to determine where to redirect.

The second option seems a little less invasive to the Devise infrastructure to me, but is a little less flexible.